# SQL update table from another table

Tags: sql

Using SQL in Access, trying to "Update" a table, with the user name, from another table.
The 3rd line below (SQLnm2...) says error-2465 cant find field '|'.
I've tried changing the expression many ways but no success.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim SQLnm As String  
Dim SQLnm2 As String  
SQLnm2 = SQLnm2 & "', '" & [Employees]![NBK] & "');"  
SQLnm = " Update tbl_DateTracking SET NBK = "  
SQLnm = SQLnm & "'" & SQLnm2 & "' WHERE "  
SQLnm = SQLnm & "CaseId = '" & CaseId & "' AND OCC_Scenario = '" & OCC_Scenario & "';"  
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLnm
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you're trying to do - since you're not sure that you're code is correct, I can't tell if you're trying to update 1 or 2 columns and with what data.

Comment: This code will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a **close bracket** where it is not opened on your third line.

> SQLnm2 = SQLnm2 & "', '" & [Employees]![name] & "');"

You are also not stating which column to update. It appears you want to update 2 columns,  the first being NBK with an empty value. The second is tricky as you either want to update your column called Name or update another column to the value of employee.name.

Your code concatenates to

> Update tbl_DateTracking 
>   SET NBK = '', 'Employee name' WHERE

Your code needs to state what column is the Employee Name.

EG

> Update tbl_DateTracking 
>   SET NBK = '', EnterColumnNameHere= 'Employee.Name'  WHERE

or maybe you meant

> Update tbl_DateTracking 
>   SET NBK = 'Employee.Name'  WHERE

Until I know how many columns you're trying to populate (and with what value), I can't provide SQL code.

As a guide for context:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value

UPDATE Persons
SET Address='Nissestien 67', City='Sandnes'
WHERE LastName='Tjessem' AND FirstName='Jakob'
```

Comment: I really approciate the replies: We are just updating one column then NBK, this is the users id and it's in the Employee table.  The Employee table has a status field (0 or 1) which is 1 for whoever is logged in and only one at a time will be logged in.  Our goal is to Update the tbl_DateTracking with the NBK. Adding code in next comment.

Comment: Dim SQLnm As String
Dim SQLnm2 As String
Dim SQLst As String

SQLnm2 = SQLnm2 & "', '" & [Employees]![NBK] & "');"
SQLnm = " Update tbl_DateTracking NBK = ,'Employees.NBK' WHERE"
SQLst =[Employees]![Status]= '1';
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLnm

Comment: The above updated code uses your suggestions/help until the WHERE.  I am trying to say WHERE Status = 1, Update the tbl_DateTracking with the users NBK.

Comment: This corrected code runs without error but does not update the table.    SQLnm2 = SQLnm2 & "', '" & [Employees]![NBK] & "');"
SQLnm = " Update tbl_DateTracking NBK = ,'Employees.NBK' WHERE"
SQLst = SQLst & "', '" & [Employees]![Status] & "' = '1';"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLnm

Comment: If you have corrected the script but it doesn't do as desired I suggest you try a new question. Also stack overflow is a site dedicated to developers (part of stack exchange).

Comment: Good advise - I've been searching and testing but now I am going to ask it another way with the subject: SQL UPDATE based on condition.

Comment: Feel free to edit your comment with a link to your new question

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim SQLnm2 As String
```

should initialize `SQLnm2` as an empty string, so

```
SQLnm2 = SQLnm2 & "', '" & [Employees]![name] & "');"
```

would produce a string `', '...');`.

```
SQLnm = " Update tbl_DateTracking SET NBK = "  
SQLnm = SQLnm & "'" & SQLnm2 & "' WHERE "
```

Then you insert that string into `SQLnm`, producing a query

```
Update tbl_DateTracking SET NBK = '', '...');' WHERE ...
```

which should probably rather be

```
Update tbl_DateTracking SET NBK = '...' WHERE ...
```

Comment: Your last comments completly confused me and my code is totally off track. Based on all the above comments could you please show me a piece of code to get back on track, based on updating one record with NBK from another table - and that table has a field called status = 1.  Not sure where I went wrong!